# how is chain rule applied to this equation

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I came across this in a DE book. It says *Observe from the chain rule that*

$$\frac{x’}{x} = \frac{d}{dt} \ln x$$

I am trying to understand how to get this equality. I do get that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln x =\frac{1}{x}$$

However, its unclear to me how the chain rule is used here to get the $\frac{d}{dt}$ on the RHS.

Comment: Think at $\,\dfrac{d}{dt} \ln x(t)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv thanks. i did get further ahead, but still not quite there :(

Comment: The prime mark is Lagrange's notation for differentiation.  Here it is implicitly used as with respect to $t$:  $$x' = \dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d t}x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule is as follows:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at the point $t \in [a, b]$. Suppose that $g$ is defined on an interval $I$ which contains the range of $f$, and $g$ is differentiable at the point $f(t)$. Define the function $h$ by
> $$
> h(s) = g(f(s)) \qquad (a \leq s \leq b).
> $$
> Then $h$ is differentiable at the point $t$, and
> $$
> h'(t) = g'(f(t)) f'(t).
> $$

In other words, the chain rule states that
$$
{\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}t}
= {\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}x} \cdot {\mathrm{d}x \over \mathrm{d}t}.
$$

---

Starting with the right-hand side, one yields
$$
{\mathrm{d}(\ln {x}) \over \mathrm{d}t}
= {\mathrm{d}(\ln {x}) \over \mathrm{d}x} \cdot {\mathrm{d}x \over \mathrm{d}t}
= \frac{1}{x} \cdot x'
= \frac{x'}{x}.
$$

It is **not correct** that
$$
{\mathrm{d}u \over \mathrm{d}t} = \ln {x(t)},
$$
in which $u = \frac{1}{x(t)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with the RHS of the equation, and expand using the chain rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\ln x = \frac{\mathrm{d}\ln x}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{x} x' = \frac{x'}{x}\,\text{.}$$